# Visual studio 2015 hanging on Ripple deploy

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, ripple

I´m having intermittently this error when trying to deploy my app to ripple

3>  Cordova 3.0 Project detected...
3>  [32mINFO: [39mCould not find cordova as a local module. Expecting to find it installed globally.

I´m running VS2015 as admin (this seemed to solve on VS2013)

Cordova is installed globally.

I tried to install cordova locally on the ripple level, but with  no luck...

If I restart it then it works fine again (at least most of the time), but it´s a terrible workaround, and kills productivity

How to fix it properly?

Answer (score 4):

Still not sure what´s the real issue.

Tracked down to the point where app.use callback is never called (inside the ripple.js file of the %AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac)

Seems that the node.exe process is, under these failing scenarios, left in some kind of inconsistent state.

At least got a workaround:

Killing nodejs.exe via the task manager and trying again.

Not ideal, but I can live with it for a while.

EDIT:

In the end, I completely reinstalled NodeJS and the bug seems to be vanished 100% this way.

Comment: Experiencing the same issues, except nodejs.exe is not even showing in my task manager under processes.

Comment: I have the same experience, which version of NodeJS you've installed, I'm wondering there's a good solution fix by Tools for Apache Cordova

Comment: Thanks for the advice Luiz, I installed a new version of node. Hope this will solve my problem